# Locust-master in Kubernetes with ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, locust

I used helm chart to run Locust on Kubernetes according to  https://github.com/deliveryhero/helm-charts/tree/master/stable/locust. I have access to the Locust UI and the master,slaves pods are running;according to the logs from the locust -master pod :

```
locust-master-76f696cf96-bs89f/INFO/locust.main: Starting web interface at http://0.0.0.0:8089 (accepting connections from all network interfaces)
locust-master-76f696cf96-bs89f/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 1.4.3
locust-master-76f696cf96-bs89f/INFO/root: Terminal was not a tty. Keyboard input disabled
locust-master-76f696cf96-bs89f/INFO/locust.runners: Client 'locust-worker-89c9d8d84-brllq_8358eeaf3e4c4b2dbafa2f4875b5cf28' reported as ready. 
Currently 1 clients ready to swarm.
```

When i "start swarming" though i see no results and according to the logs from locust-master pod i get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 999, in handle_one_response
self.run_application()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 945, in run_application
self.result = self.application(self.environ, self.start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/web.py", line 366, in wrapper
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/web.py", line 148, in swarm
user_count = int(request.form["user_count"])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
2021-04-19T21:17:03Z {'REMOTE_ADDR': '::ffff:127.0.0.1', 'REMOTE_PORT': '55086', 'HTTP_HOST': 'localhost:8089', (hidden keys: 33)} failed with ValueError
```

Any ideas what the problem might be and how could i solve this?

Comment: why are You using python 2 anyways? it is deprecated and You should use Python 3 even if You need to have python 2 using python 3 for everything else will be better

Comment: According to the logs i am using python3.8

Comment: the issue seems to be here: `user_count = int(request.form["user_count"])` which seems to be the library so it could be a version incompatibility or there is an argument to be added